# Visual Studio 2008 project configuration changes by platform/configuration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration

I've got about two dozen projects here in one solution that need changes to the include paths.  I can go through and change each one, but what's really annoying me right now is that it looks like I have to change each one four times (debug vs. release, win32 vs. x64).  Is there an easier way to do this than changing the include paths about 96 times?

As it happens, there's nothing special about the x64 configuration in these projects.  Would there be some way to copy the changes from the win32 configurations, preferably copying in multiple projects at once?

Answer (score 0):

Open *.vcproj project files as text files in Visual Studio editor and execute "Find and replace in files" function. Visual Studio project is actually plain XML file.